# Reading multiple files in Python from Excel csv

Tags: csv, operating-system, listdir

I am attempting to read files from my computer using os in python 2.7

```
import os 

path = 'C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\_Program\Stocks\AMEX'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
    data1=os.open(filename,1)
```

the program can see the files and list them for me so i know they are there. however when i try to open them with an open statement or a read statement (not shown) it does not do it.

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AMEX_20170608.csv'

I would like to open and read each file and then perform some functions. I have found several similar questions but i am on a windows machine and they do not seem to work.

has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path back in before you open the file

```
import os 

path = 'C:/Users/Owner/OneDrive/_Program/Stocks/AMEX'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
    data1=os.open(path+'/'+filename,1)
```

Comment: That does work! Thanks. How do i now read the files so i can import the contents of each into python arrays? i have tried os.read(data1) but it keeps asking for byte size? is there a web page for python beginners i can look at? Thanks for all your help

Comment: actually i think i answered my own question based on your previous answer, but not sure why it works?                                                                                                            for filename in os.listdir(path):
     with open(path +'/'+ filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line)